# Problema 3 en raya en java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un tres en raya en java, pero cuando en una linea hay 3 figuras iguales, no te comunica q has ganado, como si no entrara a la condicion,  por ahora solo comprueba en linea horizontal para probar, pero no se por que no comprueba el ganador

```
public TresEnRaya() {
    this.tablero = new String[3][3];

    //Y rellenamos el array con corchetes
    for (int i = 0; i < tablero.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tablero[i].length; j++) {
            tablero[i][j] = "[]";
        }
    }

}

//Metodo que muestra el tablero
public void muestraTablero(TresEnRaya juego) {
    for (int i = 0; i < juego.tablero.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < juego.tablero[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(juego.tablero[i][j]);
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

//Metodo que realiza un movimiento del jugador 1
public void realizaMovimiento1() {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x;
    int y;

    //Automatizamos el nombre del jugador que le toca
    System.out.println("Turno de " + Jugador.lista_jugadores.get(0).getNombre_jugador().toString());
    //Pedimos los dastos de la coordenada que va a tachar
    System.out.println("Indique la posicion X: ");
    x = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Indique la posicion Y: ");
    y = teclado.nextInt();

    //comprobamos si esa casilla ya esta ocupada
    compruebaCasillaTachada(x, y, 0);

}

//metodo que realiza un movimiento del jugador 2
public void realizaMovimiento2() {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x;
    int y;
    //Repetimos el proceso del primer metodo, pero en este caso comprobaremos si es la maquina
    System.out.println("Turno de " + Jugador.lista_jugadores.get(1).getNombre_jugador().toString());
    //Si el jugador 2 es la maquina, automatizará sus movimientos, si no le pedira por teclado los dastos al segundo jugador
    if (Jugador.lista_jugadores.get(1).getNombre_jugador().equals("Maquina")) {

        //booleano que controlara cuando sale del bucle la jugada de la maquina
        boolean jugada_maquina = false;
        Random r = new Random();
        //nos devolvera un numero aleatorio entre 0 y 2
        x = r.nextInt(3);
        y = r.nextInt(3);
        do {
            if (tablero[x][y].equals(Jugador.lista_jugadores.get(0).getSimbolo_jugador().toString())
                    || tablero[x][y].equals(Jugador.lista_jugadores.get(1).getSimbolo_jugador().toString())) {
                x = r.nextInt(3);
                y = r.nextInt(3);
            } else {
                jugada_maquina = true;
            }
        } while (jugada_maquina = false);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Indique la posicion X: ");
        x = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Indique la posicion Y: ");
        y = teclado.nextInt();
    }

    compruebaCasillaTachada(x, y, 1);

}

//Metodo que muestra el menu de juego
public int muestraMenu() {

    int opcion;
    do {
        System.out.println("------- Menu -------");
        System.out.println("1 - Contra otro Jugador");
        System.out.println("2 - Contra la maquina");
        opcion = teclado.nextInt();

        if (opcion < 1 || opcion > 2) {
            System.out.println("Error: la opcion debe ser 1 o 2.");
        }

    } while (opcion < 1 || opcion > 2);

    return opcion;
}

//Metodo que comprueba si hay o no hay un ganador
public void compruebaGanador() {


    /*El for controla la primera posicion de la matriz[esta][] 
    y va cambiando de linea hacia abajo, primero la linea 0, luego la linea 1 y para acabar la linea 2*/
    /*El segundo for, controla la segunda posicion de la matriz[][esta], iterando sobre la posicion de la linea
     empezará en la posicion[0][0], luego [0][1] y para acabar [0][2]*/
    /*Y comenzara el primer for, para pasar de la linea 0 a la linea 1, y pasará al segundo for, y mirara las posiciones de esa linea(0,1 y 2) 
    y repetira el proceso hasta a acabar con la tercera linea*/
    /*Y repetiremos el mismo bucle 2 veces para que compruebe ambos jugadores*/
    int jugador = 0;
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (tablero[i][j].toString().equals(Jugador.lista_jugadores.get(jugador).getSimbolo_jugador().toString())
                        && tablero[i][j].toString().equals(Jugador.lista_jugadores.get(jugador).getSimbolo_jugador().toString())
                        && tablero[i][j].toString().equals(Jugador.lista_jugadores.get(jugador).getSimbolo_jugador().toString())) {
                    System.out.println("Fin del Juego. El ganador es " + Jugador.lista_jugadores.get(jugador).getNombre_jugador().toString());
                }
            }
        }
        jugador++;
    } while (jugador < 2);

}

public void compruebaCasillaTachada(int x, int y, int jugador) {
    //comprobamos si esa casilla ya esta ocupada
    if (tablero[x][y].toString().equals(Jugador.lista_jugadores.get(0).getSimbolo_jugador().toString())
            || tablero[x][y].toString().equals(Jugador.lista_jugadores.get(1).getSimbolo_jugador().toString())) {
        System.out.println("ya esta tachada");
    } else {
        //Y la tachamos con el simbolo del jugador
        tablero[x][y] = "[" + Jugador.lista_jugadores.get(jugador).getSimbolo_jugador() + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No comprueba el ganador por que siempre pregunta por la misma casilla en el `if` interno del doble `for` en el metodo `void compruebaGanador()`, tiene que tener en cuenta que para que se presente un ganador hay cuatro posibilidades
Por fila, por columna o una de las dos diagonales. Por lo tanto la validación deberia ser por casos con eso eveitas recorrer la matriz

```
public boolean compruebaGanador(int x, int y, int jugador) {

    boolean ganador = false;
    String simbolo = "["+Jugador.lista_jugadores.get(jugador).getSimbolo_jugador().toString()+"]";

    //valida por fila
    if(tablero[x][0].equals(simbolo) && tablero[x][1].equals(simbolo) && tablero[x][2].equals(simbolo)){
       ganador = true;
       return ganador;
    }

    //validacion por columna
    if(tablero[0][y].equals(simbolo) && tablero[1][y].equals(simbolo) && tablero[2][y].equals(simbolo)){
       ganador = true;
       return ganador;
    }

    //validación diagonal principal
    if(tablero[0][0].equals(simbolo) && tablero[1][1].equals(simbolo) && tablero[2][2].equals(simbolo)){
        ganador = true;
       return ganador;
    }

    //validación diagonal secundaria
    if(tablero[0][2].equals(simbolo) && tablero[1][1].equals(simbolo) && tablero[2][0].equals(simbolo)){
        ganador = true;
       return ganador;
    }

    return ganador;
}
```

Este método debería ser ejecutado por cada jugada que se realice o por lo menos a partir de la quinta jugada (las primeras cuatro no dan ganador) y no esperar a que el tablero este lleno.